# Script doesn't work with ID that doesn't exist until $.getJSON appends it

Tags: javascript, jquery

This script isn't working presumably due to the load of the JSON:

```
$(function(){
    $('#fresh-button').click(function(){
        $('.blackout').fadeIn(300);
        $('.fresh-div').fadeIn(300);  
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.blackout').fadeOut(300);
            $('.fresh-div').fadeOut(300);       
        },500);    
    })
})
```

I have a div with `id=fresh-button` that doesn't exist until it's appended from $.getJSON:

```
$.getJSON('fresh_posts.php',function(data){
    data.freshposts.forEach(function(post){
      var post = '<div id="fresh-button"><div>';
      $('.main').append(post);
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation to bind the click handler, but you should also change the `id` to a `class` since `id`'s must be unique. See the documentation for the [jquery `.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for info on event delegation.

```
$('.main').on('click', '.fresh-button', function(){

...

var post = '<div class="fresh-button"><div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't listen to an element that does not yet exist, but you can listen to its parent element using event delegation:

```
 $('.main').on('click', '#fresh-button', function() { // ...
```